# Append then delete line to another line, only if it does not contain character

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

In my text file, there are 6 lines in a group separated by two blank lines. I have printed the line number for each line to the text document.

```
    365:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    366:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    367:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    368:--------------------------------------------------------------------------x-----
    369:--------------------4-----------------------------------------------------------
    370:--0-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    371:
    372:
    373:--------------------------------------------------------------------|
    374:--------------------------------------------------------------------|
    375:------------0--------2--------3h----2h----0-----2-------------------|
    376:---2-----------------------------------------------------2----------|
    377:--------------------------------------------------------------------|
    378:--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Currently only 80 characters are printed to a line, so the rest of the data continues in the next group. For example, Line 365 corresponds to Line 373.

For only lines that do not contain a vertical bar (i.e., lines 365-370), I am trying to 1) append the line that is 8 lines away, then 2) delete the appended line after it has been printed.

So, ideally:

```
    365:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    366:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    367:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------0--------2--------3h----2h----0-----2-------------------|
    368:--------------------------------------------------------------------------x--------2-----------------------------------------------------2----------|
    369:--------------------4-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    370:--0-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I can isolate the lines that do not contain a vertical bar using grep

```
grep -vn \| song.txt
```

I know that SED or AWK are likely my best bet, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Should this be done on all lines, only lines that start with —, only lines 365-370, some other selection?

Comment: As in life, in software it's much easier to do things based on what has happened than what will happen. So don't think of your problem as having to append the line that's 8 lines later, think of it as having to prepend the line that was 8 lines earlier - that should make the solution much more obvious.

Comment: @Cyrus added! thank you for the suggestion. New here.

Comment: @JimDanner only lines without the vertical bar should be appended by the line that is 8 lines later

Answer (score 2):

Just massage this approach to suit:

```
$ seq 16 | awk 'NR>8{print a[NR%8], $0} {a[NR%8]=$0}'
1 9
2 10
3 11
4 12
5 13
6 14
7 15
8 16
```

e.g. assuming 2 blank lines at the end of your input to make it blocks of 8 lines:

```
$ awk 'NR>8{print a[NR%8] $0} {a[NR%8]=$0}' file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------0--------2--------3h----2h----0-----2-------------------|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------x-------2-----------------------------------------------------2----------|
-------------------4------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
-0------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

or if you don't have those blank lines after the last block:

```
$ awk '!NF{next} ++cnt>6{print a[NR%6] $0} {a[NR%6]=$0}' file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------x------------------------------------------------------------------------|
-------------------4----------------------------------------------------------------------0--------2--------3h----2h----0-----2-------------------|
-0-------------------------------------------------------------------------------2-----------------------------------------------------2----------|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit ugly, but working:

Split your input:

```
egrep -v "^$|\|" song.txt >file1
egrep    "\|"    song.txt >file2
```

And put it together:

```
paste -d "" file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `vim` program for this type of work. For example, assuming you have a file named `file_name.txt` with the following content

```
-------------------------8----
------------0--------2--------|
---2--------------------------|
------------------aaa---------|

---------------984asds--------|
---------t6776----------------|
```

with the following command

```
vim -c ":6y" -c ":put" -c ":1" -c ":join!" -c ":6d" -c ":wq" file_name.txt
```

the program opens `file_name.txt` on the first line, copy the sixth line, paste the contents copied in the second line (the next line), go to the first line, joins the first line with the second, delete the line that was copied (sixth line), save and close the file. In this way, this command produces the following result

```
-------------------------8-------------------984asds--------|
------------0--------2--------|
---2--------------------------|
------------------aaa---------|

---------t6776----------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU utils);

```
sed '/^$/d' file |
split -nr/6 --filter 'cat'|
paste -sd'\0'|
sed 's/|/&\n/g;s/\n$//'
```

This removes any blank lines using sed, splits the file into 6 using a round-robin method and instead of making separate files, outputs all the files interleaved into the stdout. The lines are then pasted into a long lines (one per string) and split back into shorter lines using the `|` as record separators.